# Edit (pencil) icon shows but not possible to click on it?

Tags: support, status-completed, comments

Multiple times it happened that the edit/pencil icon (by comment) was showing but it was not possible to click on it and edit the comment.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pencil icon [image] next to a *comment* means that the comment has been edited in the past - it is not clickable.

I edited the comment I added above - you can see the icon on the end that indicates that the comment has been edited:

[image]

To edit a comment you need to mouse over the comment and wait for the `edit` link to appear.  You can only edit your own comments, and only for 5 minutes after you have commented.  After that time you are unable to edit the comment.

Note the `edit` link at the end:

[image]

See [Why is the time limit for editing comments only 5 minutes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78573/why-is-the-time-limit-for-editing-comments-only-5-minutes)

If you *need* to edit your comment after the 5 minute timeout, you can <s>flag the comment and ask a moderator to edit it (with an explanation), or</s> delete the comment and add a new one.  (**edit** It appears you cannot flag your own *comment* for moderator attention)

Comment: I think 1 of the issues [in there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78573/why-is-the-time-limit-for-editing-comments-only-5-minutes) was that the need for deleting and adding new one may break the order of comments then

Comment: @Abc1 It appears you are unable to flag your own comment.  I will adjust my answer

Comment: I have never noticed that pencil icon before and was wondering what this question was asking.